# Search in C++ code for where an object is instanced

Tags: c++

Have to work with a HUGE codebase where data is carried through multiple layers plus literally three frameworks and often have the need to find those specific .cpp files and lines where an instance of a custom class or struct is actually "created" (sorry for the lack of a better word).
Using "search all references" in an IDE (VSCode in my case) yields too many other results.

The equivalent to what I look for in Java would be just "new CLASS_NAME" as that's the only syntax to instantiate classes in Java. But C++ is more complex...

Is there any way to achieve this? One that also works when the instances are created through non-standard containers?

Comment: Put some instrumentation into the constructor.

Comment: Or just delete the constructor and look at the compiler errors.

Comment: @Mansoor By instrumentation you mean markers like breakpoints active at runtime?
Unfortunately recompiling the software takes 1-3 minutes so those are unfortunately slow ways.

Comment: Why don't you just use match-case search with the class name?

Comment: @Saisai3396 Wouldn't this match any reference or pointer of this type as well?

Comment: @Saisai3396 Because that yields me every place this class is mentioned and all and not only instantiation. Edit: Exactly, and one framework takes some of those classes as templates (but doesn't actually create instances).

Comment: I think a regex could be defined for all kinds of possible instances of a class of a given name but I'm not too sure.

Comment: Something along these lines should work. I am not really good with regex but this will give you an idea. ClassName\(|ClassName ([a-zA-Z_$0-9]) =|ClassName ([a-zA-Z_$0-9]);|ClassName ([a-zA-Z_$0-9]); 

The regex is checking for 'ClassName(', 'Classname varname;', 'Classname varname =' strings

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made a regex for finding different possible types of instantiations in C++;

```
(^|\s?)ClassName(\s?)+\(|(^|\s?)ClassName(\s+)([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,31})(\s+)=( ?|\s+)|(^|\s?)ClassName(\s+)([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,31})(\s?)+;|new(\s+)ClassName|(^|\s?)ClassName(\s+)([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,31})(\s?)+\(|(^|\s?)ClassName\<
```

The regex looks for the following strings and I tested it out for a 'ClassName' class in VSCode with regex and match-case used together;

- ClassName(
- Classname varname;
- Classname varname =
- new Classname
- ClassName varname(
- ClassName< (templates)

I'm not too sure if this will cover all the cases (just update the regex if you find 'em) of class instantiation, but I think it should work with those in which the class name or its constructor is used.

Example of what this looks [like](http://regexr.com/4pqe3).

Comment: won't work with typenames in templates, typedefs, comments, uniform initialization syntax, arbitrary whitespacing, macros, not being a full statement, constructors with more than one parameter, constructors with parameter with name containing $, implicit conversions, nested scopes with a different class with the same name, classes with a suffix "ClassName", unevaluated contexts, and probably more... A regex is never a way to do stuff like this

Comment: Still this is more than nothing at least! Thank you, I will try it.

Comment: Thanks @Sopel for mentioning the problems. I tried updating the regex to deal with arbitrary spaces/tabs/newlines, not full statements, and suffixes with "ClassName". I am not sure though why would this not work with constructors with one or more parameters since the regex is only looking for a opening bracket (. Indeed this would not work with complex situtaions such as macros, nested scopes, aliases, etc.

Comment: @AlexGeorg I know this does not fit the answer well but as long as it helps! (:

Comment: @Saisai3396 It did help! I did omit the last matcher from yours and that reduced the results to just 5 of which one was the typedef that was renaming the type only for that portion of the code that produces the instances...